# Double Animation Forcing Translation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation

I am trying to implement a translation animation on a Grid in Windows Phone 8.

The behavior that I want to implement is that when the user drags from left to right a new panel comes from the left(in animation) and reverse happens when the user drags from right to left.

For this I have implemented the following code which is called on Manipulation_Completed :

```
public Storyboard AnimateContent(int direction)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

        if (direction == 1)
        {   //content_trans is the object of composite transform of grid 
            animation.From =content_trans.TranslateX;
            animation.To = 370;
        }
        else if(direction==0)
        {

            animation.From = content_trans.TranslateX;
            animation.To = 0;
        }


        animation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,500);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Content);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

        sb.Children.Add(animation);
        return sb;
    }
```

Now problem I am facing is that after calling this function(and calling begin() on storyboard object), when I am writing

```
content_trans.TranslateX=250;//or any other value of my choice
```

it is not being reflected on the screen.

I want to change these values because I writing this line of code in Manipulation_Delta , so that the user can have a feeling of dragging something, but it is not being reflected after animation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because animated values take precedence over local values. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing)

If you want to set the value yourself, you will need to stop the animation first.

**EDIT:** If you want to be able to drag after the animation, then set the END location manually just before animating, and tell the animation to stop applying itself when it finishes with:

```
animation.FillBehaviour = FillBehaviour.Stop;
```

This means that when the animation finishes, your local values will apply.

Comment: Thanks for this, And plz tell me that is my approach to do this is correct or not ??